# MySQL query DATE comparison

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a problem with my query. Its giving me the correct result for some cases and for some it does not, so if anyone could tell me what to change it'd be amazing cause I'm stuck with it for some time now. Here is my table data:

Table reservation_logs:

```
log_id      int(15) auto_increment   Primary   Unique  
room_log    int(10)         
dt_from     date                
dt_until    date
```

Table apartments:

```
apartman_id     int(10) auto_increment   Primary   Unique   
apartman_name   int(10)
```

My php code for date:

```
$date_from = 'text input date';
$date_until = 'text input date';

$myquery = ("SELECT * FROM reservation_logs WHERE room_log = '$apartman_id'  
AND(((dt_from >= '$date_from' AND dt_from <= '$date_until') 
AND (dt_until >= '$date_until' OR dt_until <= '$date_until')))");
```

Now I input some dates I should get correct `apartman_id`, if its busy or not. Here is case when this is working: when `$date_from` equals 1st day in the month and `$date_until` equals last day in a month. But for example if I choose dates `$date_from` equals 16th of the month and `$date_until` equals 17th of the month I get incorrect results if room is busy from 15th of the month until 19th lets say. I hope I didn't complicate too much I just wanted for more people to get idea behind this.

Comment: This is not directly related to your question but you have some serious SQL Injection vulnerabilities in this code that you should definitely clean up. Make sure you wrap all input to your query in mysql_real_escape_string() or some similar function.

Comment: This is just practice m8, it will never see the web I assure you

Comment: Keep in mind that, internally, date columns include both the date and time.  If you wanted to select all dates from the 15th to including the 16th, you would need dt >= 15th and dt < 17th (i.e. 16th at 11:59.59.999 PM or earlier)

Comment: Not the case, not working .. tnx

Comment: @EricJ, that's not correct, a date column just contains a date, and its sufficient to do dt<='2009-09-22' to get dates up to and including 2009-09-22

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find bookings between $date_from and $date_until, even if they just overlap this date range? Something as simply as this should suffice...

```
SELECT * FROM reservation_logs WHERE room_log = '$apartman_id'  
AND dt_from <= $date_until 
AND dt_until >= $date_from ;
```

It simply excludes any booking which starts *after* your date range, and any booking which finishes *before* your date range. Anything that remains must be in the date range or overlapping it.

Comment: well that's a pretty standard idiom - suspect it's the format your date_until and _date_from variables then.

Comment: Format of column is date like '2009-09-22'

Comment: Did you put quotes around the dates?  Otherwise 2009-09-22 is an arithmetic expression yielding the integer 1978.

Answer (score -1):

```
dt_until >= '$date_until' OR dt_until <= '$date_until'
```

Will always be true...

Comment: is there a link between this and post below, when I used combination of 2 with AND nothing worked while using OR all were busy ..

Answer (score -1):

```
dt_from >= '$date_from' AND dt_from <= '$date_until'
```

...and this is only true if `$date_from` = `$date_until`.